# ValueError: time data '27th August 2017 23:32:58' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, odo

i am using pandas and odo to import csv files into a database, there is a date field in file with this format `27th August 2017 23:06:25` i would like to convert is to this format `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S`.

Here is my the piece of code i am using:

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')`

I end up with the error

`ValueError: time data '27th August 2017 23:32:58' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)`

Anyone having an idea solving this? please

Comment: Why do you expect `'27th August 2017'` to fit the format `'%d-%m-%Y'`? It's not even close.

Comment: @DeepSpace OP states " i would like to convert is to this format". So he doesn't know that this format is used for _parsing_. Not that bad a question after all, since pandas is able to parse the input date without any format (and I learned something)

Comment: I believe that OP has not yet read the documentation on how datetime's formats work and thus his expectations are incorrect. Here it is: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` can parse this fine without a format specifier:

```
In[25]:
pd.to_datetime('27th August 2017 23:32:58')

Out[25]: Timestamp('2017-08-27 23:32:58')
```

So you don't need to state the format for this example

The other point here is that even if you tried something like:

```
In[28]:
pd.to_datetime('27th August 2017 23:32:58', format='%dth %B %Y %H:%M:%S')

Out[28]: Timestamp('2017-08-27 23:32:58')
```

Which does work it will fail for date strings like:

`'3rd June 2011 12:11:23'`

because of the `'rd'`, you can't pass a format to handle the day format using `to_datetime`, see the python [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) reference. You would need to strip those out in order for it to work but `pandas` is man/woman enough to sniff the format so there is no need

Comment: But if you do specify the format, recognize that %m is "08" not "August"!

Comment: @JohnZwinck sorry are you commenting to me or the OP here?

Comment: To the OP of course.  I know you know %m is not "August".

Comment: @JohnZwinck sure, no worries